# Why is using a macro in my code causing an error and how can I fix it?

Tags: c, macros, exit, status, factorial

I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define fctrl(N) ( (N==1)? (N) : (N*fctrl(N-1)) )

int main()
{
    int m,n=7;
    m = fctrl(n);
    printf("fctrl is %d\n",m);
    return 0;
}
```

While compiling, I got the following error:

```
/tmp/ccRODXnZ.o: In function `main':
/home//Desktop/fctrl/fctrl.c:8: undefined reference to `fctrl'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why was this error displayed and how can I fix it?

Comment: Makros do Not expand recuesively.

Comment: @Lazcano "Macros are just like any other tool - a hammer used in a murder is not evil because it's a hammer. It is evil in the way the person uses it in that way. If you want to hammer in nails, a hammer is a perfect tool.". Use them right and you will be fine! ;)

Comment: http://googleweblight.com/i?u=http://nealabq.com/blog/2008/08/14/the-c-preprocessor-recursion/&grqid=mV7Ox5fU&hl=en-IN&geid=1005

Comment: @StephanLechner Yes they are expanded recursively (otherwise you couldn't use macros in macros). The problem is more subtle: if a macro identifier was expanded once, it will not be expanded in further expansions. The details are in the C Standard :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are not processed by the "actual" C compiler. Macros are processed by c-preprocessor which is merely a text replacement mechanism thus your function-like expression defined as a macro and intended to work as a function does not result with normal function behavior.

After preprocessing takes place, your program will take the following structure,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m,n=7;
    m = ( (n==1)? (n) : (n*fctrl(n-1)) );
    printf("fctrl is %d\n",m);
    return 0;
}
```

The question you should ask yourself is where is fctrl function defined? The answer is obvious, **it is not defined** and that's main reason why you are getting `undefined reference to 'fctrl'` error.

Use `cpp -nostdinc {filename}` or `gcc -E -nostdinc {filename}` commands on terminal and you will figure out what's going on. By the way, `-nostdinc` is used to supress inclusion of system header files. `cpp` is the program to invoke C/C++ preprocessor despite the fact that C/C++ preprocessor can be used for purposes more than mere C/C++ text replacement mechanism. `gcc -E` option gives the same results with `cpp` command. In the early days of Unix, preprocessor and compilers used to be separate programs. They are bundled together in today's operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to define a macro that emulates a recursive function, but macros do not support recursiveness, thus the error.

I would use a function instead, but you always read more in [C preprocessor, recursive macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641836/c-preprocessor-recursive-macros).